# axios call in a method with vuejs and nuxt

Tags: vue.js, axios, nuxt.js

For each country in my list of countries i need to make an api call with axios to get another value, here is y component :

```
<template>
  <div>
    <div v-for="(country, i) in countries" :key="i">
      <div>{{ county[i.id].count }}</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

In my script i call my method matchCount on mounted and store the value in my county data object :

```
<script>
export default {
  props: {
   countries: {
    type: Array,
    required: true
    }
  },
 data() {
  return {
    county = {}
  };
 },
 mounted() {
  this.matchCount();
 },
 methods: {
   matchCount() {
     var paysCount = this.pays;
     paysCount.forEach(item => {
       this.$axios
        .get(
          `https://api.com/federation/}/${item.id}/`
        )
        .then(response => {
          this.county[item.id] = {};
          this.county[item.id].count = response.data.length.toString();
        });
     });
   }
  }
};
</script>
```

I get this error "TypeError: Cannot read property 'count' of undefined", how should i call this method ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will find useful using the following syntax in your HTML templates `{{variable[key] && variable[key].value}}`.

In your particular case it would be:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <div v-for="(country, i) in countries" :key="i">
      <div>{{ county[i.id] && county[i.id].count }}</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

What it does, is essentially verifying if the key `i.id` exists in `county` array. If not, it will not throw error about missing objects / keys.

You can use this syntax when using objects too as following:

```
<div v-text="house.dog && house.dog.name" ></div>
```

If `dog` is in the `house` object then it will show `dog's` name.

**Edit:**

Add `this.$forceUpdate();` to the function:

```
matchCount() {
 var paysCount = this.pays;
 paysCount.forEach(item => {
   this.$axios
    .get(
      `https://api.com/federation/}/${item.id}/`
    )
    .then(response => {
      this.county[item.id] = {};
      this.county[item.id].count = response.data.length.toString();
      this.$forceUpdate();
    });
 });
}
```

Comment: it doesnt work in the first render, my count properties appears only if something change in my component.

Comment: seems i've  never heard about that...im going to dig the documentation, its so cool !

Comment: A little suggestion: if you make so many calls to your server, it's going to affect the performance of your webpage. Try to make it all in one call (if you can) and then call `forceUpdate`. For smaller apps that's fine, but for large ones it's not. + `this.$forceUpdate` will update everything in Vue root and it's components taking some time on each iteration of the loop.

Comment: Ur suggestion seems necessary in fact so im gonna try to do that in another way.

Answer (score 1):

`county[item.id].count` is set asynchronously, it might not be available when you render the component. You can add a safe check:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <div v-for="(country, i) in countries" :key="i">
      <div v-if="county[i.id]">{{ county[i.id].count }}</div>
      <div v-else>Loading...</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

and it seems that you have [reactivity problem](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#Change-Detection-Caveats):

```
this.$axios
    .get(
      `https://api.com/federation/}/${item.id}/`
    )
    .then(response => {
      this.$set(this.county, item.id, {count: response.data.length.toString())
    });
```

Comment: i tried this but in this case nothing appears, but my county object is full of data.

Comment: It seems that you have reactivity problem. I've update the answer. Please try it!